# Azure - Add PTR record to Linux VM (Resource Manager)

Tags: linux, azure, reverse-dns

I want to add a PTR record to my Linux VM on Azure (resource manager)
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/

I know what PTR record is, ;) I have also read other posts, and Azure doc:

https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/blog/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/

The problem is the doc is for virtual machines created in classical mode, not for virtual machines in resource mode.

Does anyone have experience with that? How do you use your mail servers on Azure without PTR record? ...

I have also try to change DNS servers form azure to external and then try to add PTR record but after 8h I don't see any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In classic deployments the IP, and the reverse DNS entry were part of the cloud service that held your VM's, and so as you mentioned all the configuration was done there.

In the new resource manager world cloud services don't exist and public IP's have become their own independent entity which you then associate with a VM or a load balancer. The reverse DNS setup is now associated with the public IP.

You can create a reverse DNS entry when you create a new IP using the [New-AzurePublicIpAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/mt126026.aspx) PowerShell command using the -ReverseFqdn switch which takes a string value. Unfortunately there does not seem to be a way to create it through the portal.